# changing the value of bin in a record of aerospike db which is of map type in lua script

Tags: lua, user-defined-functions, lua-table, aerospike

say aerospike database is having recorded data like below

let the namespace be employee

```
name age characteristics  
sachin 25 MAP('{"weight":70, "height":25}')
```

now i want to change the value of height which is inside map for all the records in employee namespace through lua script.

i have tried for changing the bins of normal data type as below , i,e i 
tried to change the age as below:

```
function changeAgeOfEmployee(rec)
  if not aerospike:exists(rec) then
     error ("Invalid Record. Returning")
     return
  else
     age = 30
     rec['age'] = age
     aerospike:update(rec)
  end
end
```

but i am not sure how to change the value in map in lua, can somebody please assist me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MAP` data-type is basically a lua table. MAP in lua can be written as:

```
local m = map {"weight" => 70, "height" => 25}
```

To loop over all the key/value pairs you should use the [pairs iterator](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/map.html) like this:

```
for key, value in map.pairs(m) do
    m[key] = 30 --this changes all the values of your MAP to 30
end
```

Comment: See the Aerospike [Lua UDF API reference](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api_reference.html).

Comment: Thanks for that @Ronen Botzer! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to modify a key of a map, or an index of a list, you should cast that bin to a local variable, then set it back to the record ahead of updating it.

```
function changes(rec)
  rec['i'] = 99
  local m = rec['m']
  m['a'] = 66
  rec['m'] = m
  aerospike:update(rec)
end
```

In AQL

```
$ aql
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.15.1.2
C Client Version 4.3.0
Copyright 2012-2017 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql> register module './test.lua'
OK, 1 module added.
aql> select * from test.demo where PK='88'
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| i  | s     | m                                    | l                                        |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| 88 | "xyz" | MAP('{"a":2, "b":4, "c":8, "d":16}') | LIST('[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, NIL, 128, 256]') |
+----+-------+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.002 secs)

aql> execute test.changes() on test.demo where PK='88'
+---------+
| changes |
+---------+
|         |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 secs)

aql> select * from test.demo where PK='88'
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| i  | s     | m                                     | l                                        |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| 99 | "xyz" | MAP('{"a":66, "b":4, "c":8, "d":16}') | LIST('[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, NIL, 128, 256]') |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 secs)
```

Comment: Thanks for spending your valuable time on replying this , same thing i tried and it worked for me, thanks a lot , have a good time